# how to remove shower tap

Tags: shower

I have some shower taps and shower head I am trying to remove so I can replace the back splash wall, how do you remove this sort of tap and head? I tried just turning it, but had no luck , not wanting to damage things, so thought I should ask before preceding

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally turning the pipe anti clockwise will unscrew the pipe from the threaded elbow in the wall. Looking at your top photo I would bet that is the correct advice but the 2nd photo looks like the valve, you will need to remove the cover it may be held in place with a set screw or grub screw if it doesn’t unscrew. Then you should be able to remove the surround or back splash.

I would make sure that corner is sealed with your new work as that is a place where a lot of water can enter the wall and cause rot.